# Zabbix monitoring httpd service via SNMP

Tags: snmp, service, zabbix

I have use Nagios, but im forced now to use zabbix, can someone gave me some hints on how to monitor the httpd service, or any other service on a Linux Box ? What i want to achieve is to monitor the Httpd service, ipsec, pluto, etc. but via snmpv3. I already have the following....

put the "proc name-of-process" in snmpd.conf, have configured username and password etc. and i have triggered the snmpget and snmpwalk. So this part works fine. Using the UCD-SNMP-MIB::prCount MIB i have information. What i need is simple UP/Down status of the process. And can't figure out how to do it on Zabbix and what exact Mib to use it.

Any hint/suggestion is welcome !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In zabbix, you easily add an item with key **proc.num[httpd]** (with httpd means your processes name)  into your host or your template to monitor httpd deamon. To create an item in zabbix, please visit: [link](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/item)

Comment: Ye this is correct but you use this method when you monitoring the hosts using the zabbix agent, when you using the SNMP there is different approach here